# Nvidia module null pointer dereference in boot up

Tags: 14.04, boot, nvidia, kernel, kinect

I was trying to get [KinectFusion via PCL](http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/using_kinfu_large_scale.php) running on my Ubuntu 14.04 machine working with a Microsoft Kinect v1 sensor and also an Asus Xtion Pro sensor. For some reason the sample code was freezing, so I unplugged one of these sensor USB devices and when it still was frozen, I restarted my computer. However, now on boot up I get stuck on a black screen. The /var/log/kern.log file shows the following for the boot up:

```
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.532422] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.532424] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.537407] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.557757] EXT4-fs (sda1): re-mounted. Opts: errors=remount-ro
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.567443] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at           (null)
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.567598] IP: [<ffffffff8172a91b>] __down_common+0x4c/0x144
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.567707] PGD 4239b5067 PUD 4277fd067 PMD 0 
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.567913] Oops: 0002 [#1] SMP 
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.568067] Modules linked in: nvidia(POX+) snd_hda_codec_realtek drm snd_hda_intel(+) snd_hda_codec snd_hwdep snd_pcm snd_page_alloc snd_seq_midi snd_seq_midi_event snd_rawmidi eeepc_wmi asus_wmi sparse_keymap mxm_wmi x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp coretemp kvm_intel kvm crct10dif_pclmul crc32_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel aesni_intel snd_seq aes_x86_64 lrw gf128mul snd_seq_device glue_helper ablk_helper snd_timer cryptd snd serio_raw mei_me mei soundcore video shpchp wmi acpi_pad mac_hid parport_pc ppdev lp parport e1000e ahci psmouse ptp libahci pps_core
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.571143] CPU: 4 PID: 617 Comm: nvidia-persiste Tainted: P           OX 3.13.0-66-generic #108-Ubuntu
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.571224] Hardware name: ASUS All Series/Z97-A, BIOS 2012 09/30/2014
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.571280] task: ffff880424460000 ti: ffff880426f20000 task.ti: ffff880426f20000
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.571337] RIP: 0010:[<ffffffff8172a91b>]  [<ffffffff8172a91b>] __down_common+0x4c/0x144
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.571443] RSP: 0018:ffff880426f21b48  EFLAGS: 00010096
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.571497] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: ffffffffa0d87410 RCX: 0000000000000000
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.571566] RDX: ffffffffa0d87418 RSI: ffff880426f21b50 RDI: ffffffffa0d87410
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.571644] RBP: ffff880426f21b98 R08: 0000000000000296 R09: ffffffffa0984c7b
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.571715] R10: 0000000000000014 R11: ffffffffffffffc0 R12: 7fffffffffffffff
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.571784] R13: ffff880424460000 R14: 0000000000000002 R15: 0000000000000000
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.571858] FS:  00007f02dfd92740(0000) GS:ffff88043ed00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.571985] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.572054] CR2: 0000000000000000 CR3: 0000000426266000 CR4: 00000000001407e0
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.572157] DR0: 0000000000000000 DR1: 0000000000000000 DR2: 0000000000000000
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.572249] DR3: 0000000000000000 DR6: 00000000fffe0ff0 DR7: 0000000000000400
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.572346] Stack:
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.572422]  0000000000000000 ffffffffa0d87418 0000000000000000 ffff8804239d12b8
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.572689]  0000000000000000 ffffffffa0d87410 ffff880426690000 ffff880426058f00
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.572977]  0000000000000002 00000000000000ff ffff880426f21ba8 ffffffff8172aa30
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.573258] Call Trace:
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.573326]  [<ffffffff8172aa30>] __down+0x1d/0x1f
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.573397]  [<ffffffff810b0f71>] down+0x41/0x50
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.573536]  [<ffffffffa0985057>] nvidia_open+0x467/0x930 [nvidia]
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.573646]  [<ffffffffa098ff49>] nvidia_frontend_open+0x49/0xa0 [nvidia]
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.573721]  [<ffffffff811c2d4f>] chrdev_open+0x9f/0x1d0
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.573797]  [<ffffffff811bb883>] do_dentry_open+0x233/0x2e0
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.573870]  [<ffffffff811c2cb0>] ? cdev_put+0x30/0x30
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.573940]  [<ffffffff811bbbb9>] vfs_open+0x49/0x50
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.574010]  [<ffffffff811ccf64>] do_last+0x564/0x1240
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.574078]  [<ffffffff811caa21>] ? link_path_walk+0x71/0x880
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.574149]  [<ffffffff8131615b>] ? apparmor_file_alloc_security+0x5b/0x180
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.574220]  [<ffffffff811cdcfb>] path_openat+0xbb/0x650
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.574288]  [<ffffffff810c949d>] ? call_rcu_sched+0x1d/0x20
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.574359]  [<ffffffff811cf0fa>] do_filp_open+0x3a/0x90
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.574431]  [<ffffffff811dbf77>] ? __alloc_fd+0xa7/0x130
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.574508]  [<ffffffff811bd6d9>] do_sys_open+0x129/0x280
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.574580]  [<ffffffff811bd84e>] SyS_open+0x1e/0x20
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.574654]  [<ffffffff81734c5d>] system_call_fastpath+0x1a/0x1f
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.574724] Code: 54 49 89 d4 48 8d 57 08 53 48 89 fb 48 83 e4 f0 48 83 ec 28 48 8b 47 10 48 8d 74 24 08 48 89 54 24 08 48 89 44 24 10 48 89 77 10 <48> 89 30 4c 89 f0 4c 89 6c 24 18 83 e0 01 c6 44 24 20 00 48 89 
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.578860] RIP  [<ffffffff8172a91b>] __down_common+0x4c/0x144
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.578977]  RSP <ffff880426f21b48>
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.579040] CR2: 0000000000000000
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.579105] ---[ end trace 6f5428ed50ba31b9 ]---
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.585759] usb 3-13: new low-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.618163] usb 3-13: New USB device found, idVendor=413c, idProduct=2105
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.618252] usb 3-13: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.618366] usb 3-13: Product: Dell USB Keyboard
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.618458] usb 3-13: Manufacturer: Dell
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.618636] usb 3-13: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 128 microframes, ep desc says 192 microframes
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.671128] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.17
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.671229] NET: Registered protocol family 31
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.671312] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.671404] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.671489] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.671585] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.674431] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.674483] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.674488] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.674491] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.674714] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.674832] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.794062] usb 3-14: new low-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.814379] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.814774] usb 3-14: New USB device found, idVendor=045e, idProduct=0039
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.814843] usb 3-14: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=3, SerialNumber=0
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.814925] usb 3-14: Product: Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM)
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.814999] usb 3-14: Manufacturer: Microsoft
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.815167] usb 3-14: ep 0x81 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.829873] hidraw: raw HID events driver (C) Jiri Kosina
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.841903] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.841982] usbhid: USB HID core driver
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.843394] input: Dell Dell USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-13/3-13:1.0/input/input15
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.844036] hid-generic 0003:413C:2105.0002: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Dell Dell USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-13/input0
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.844201] input: Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM) as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-14/3-14:1.0/input/input16
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.844456] hid-generic 0003:045E:0039.0003: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Microsoft Microsoft 5-Button Mouse with IntelliEye(TM)] on usb-0000:00:14.0-14/input0
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.845408] input: 3M 3M MicroTouch USB controller as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-10/3-10:1.0/input/input17
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.845605] hid-multitouch 0003:0596:0502.0001: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Pointer [3M 3M MicroTouch USB controller] on usb-0000:00:14.0-10/input0
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.882309] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input19
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.882520] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input18
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.882715] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input14
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.882913] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input13
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.885020] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:01:00.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=none
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.904256] /dev/vmmon[1074]: Module vmmon: registered with major=10 minor=165
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.904363] /dev/vmmon[1074]: Module vmmon: initialized
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.914290] Guest personality initialized and is inactive
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.914874] VMCI host device registered (name=vmci, major=10, minor=56)
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.914964] Initialized host personality
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.918306] e1000e 0000:00:19.0: irq 43 for MSI/MSI-X
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.918505] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.918825] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.932526] NET: Registered protocol family 40
Oct 26 16:55:24 myPC kernel: [    1.984292] random: nonblocking pool is initialized
Oct 26 16:55:25 myPC kernel: [    2.487169] Switched to clocksource tsc
Oct 26 16:55:25 myPC kernel: [    2.517629] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 1315 (vmnet-netifup)
Oct 26 16:55:25 myPC kernel: [    2.517635] /dev/vmnet: hub 1 does not exist, allocating memory.
Oct 26 16:55:25 myPC kernel: [    2.517642] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 1 successfully opened
Oct 26 16:55:25 myPC kernel: [    2.526776] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 1317 (vmnet-dhcpd)
Oct 26 16:55:25 myPC kernel: [    2.526783] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 1 successfully opened
Oct 26 16:55:25 myPC kernel: [    2.531368] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 1328 (vmnet-natd)
Oct 26 16:55:25 myPC kernel: [    2.531372] /dev/vmnet: hub 8 does not exist, allocating memory.
Oct 26 16:55:25 myPC kernel: [    2.531379] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 8 successfully opened
Oct 26 16:55:25 myPC kernel: [    2.532882] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 1329 (vmnet-netifup)
Oct 26 16:55:25 myPC kernel: [    2.532887] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 8 successfully opened
Oct 26 16:55:25 myPC kernel: [    2.537544] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 1332 (vmnet-dhcpd)
Oct 26 16:55:25 myPC kernel: [    2.537552] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 8 successfully opened
Oct 26 16:55:25 myPC kernel: [    2.562324] vboxdrv: Found 8 processor cores.
Oct 26 16:55:25 myPC kernel: [    2.562547] vboxdrv: fAsync=0 offMin=0x24f offMax=0x3027
Oct 26 16:55:25 myPC kernel: [    2.562618] vboxdrv: TSC mode is 'synchronous', kernel timer mode is 'normal'.
Oct 26 16:55:25 myPC kernel: [    2.562620] vboxdrv: Successfully loaded version 4.3.10_Ubuntu (interface 0x001a0007).
Oct 26 16:55:25 myPC kernel: [    2.569911] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
Oct 26 16:55:27 myPC kernel: [    4.807747] e1000e: eth0 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
Oct 26 16:55:27 myPC kernel: [    4.807776] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): eth0: link becomes ready
Oct 26 16:55:27 myPC kernel: [    4.807922] /dev/vmnet: open called by PID 1265 (vmnet-bridge)
Oct 26 16:55:27 myPC kernel: [    4.807928] /dev/vmnet: hub 0 does not exist, allocating memory.
Oct 26 16:55:27 myPC kernel: [    4.807946] /dev/vmnet: port on hub 0 successfully opened
Oct 26 16:55:27 myPC kernel: [    4.807954] bridge-eth0: up
Oct 26 16:55:27 myPC kernel: [    4.807955] bridge-eth0: attached
Oct 26 16:55:27 myPC kernel: [    5.008155] userif-2: sent link down event.
Oct 26 16:55:27 myPC kernel: [    5.008157] userif-2: sent link up event.
Oct 26 16:55:28 myPC kernel: [    6.045987] userif-2: sent link down event.
Oct 26 16:55:28 myPC kernel: [    6.045990] userif-2: sent link up event.
```

It seems that my NVIDIA drivers or something got updated at some point so that there now is a dereferenced a null pointer during start-up and it's "tainting" the kernel. I'm not sure if this is from my unplugging one of the sensors and restarting the computer while it was frozen, or if it's due to another issue that coincidentally arose while I was trying to install PCL's KinectFusion implementation.

I've tried restarting the computer many times but I always get the same result (including the same logs as above). What's the easiest way to get my computing back to a normal state?

Comment: [This forum](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/880817/-solved-kernel-module-null-pointer-error-with-gtx550-and-ubuntu-14-04/) mentioned updated the kernel to 3.19 using linux-generic-lts-vivid package worked to solve something that looks similar if not the same as my problem. I'll try this tomorrow, unless someone else knows a better solution!

Answer (score 0):

Following [this forum post](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/880817/-solved-kernel-module-null-pointer-error-with-gtx550-and-ubuntu-14-04/) and [this blog post](http://codeyarns.com/2015/03/30/nvidia-module-taints-linux-kernel/) and other results from Googling, I did the following and was able to load Ubuntu and get into the desktop. I did this through ssh from another computer:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-vivid
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
# change two lines to:
# GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
# GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="rcutree.rcu_idle_gp_delay=1" 
sudo update-grub
```

Specifically, I added "nomodeset" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT and "rcutree.rcu_idle_gp_delay=1" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX. I'm not sure which of these 3 things solved it, but now it's working.

There are still some strange things in the /var/log/kern.log file about the nvidia module. Does anyone know if this these logs are typical/normal or should I be trying to fix it as well? There's no more null pointer dereferencing though. See below:

```
Oct 27 09:22:03 myPC kernel: [    1.602119] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.                                                                                                                                                                             
Oct 27 09:22:03 myPC kernel: [    1.602120] Disabling lock debugging due to kernel taint                                                                                                                                                                               
Oct 27 09:22:03 myPC kernel: [    1.609378] nvidia: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel                                                                                                                               
Oct 27 09:22:03 myPC kernel: [    1.614709] vgaarb: device changed decodes: PCI:0000:01:00.0,olddecodes=io+mem,decodes=none:owns=io+mem                                                                                                                                
Oct 27 09:22:03 myPC kernel: [    1.615034] [drm] Initialized nvidia-drm 0.0.0 20150116 for 0000:01:00.0 on minor 0                                                                                                                                                    
Oct 27 09:22:03 myPC kernel: [    1.615038] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  340.93  Wed Aug 19 16:49:15 PDT 2015
```